# Move views pager to top of node instead of bottom

Tags: views, 6, paging

Is there a simple way to move views' pager to a different place than the default bottom?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the View UI. Click Theme: information. The top list item will say Display output. There are several file names to go from the least specific to the most specific. These are the choices to override the default View template for Display output. If you want every view pager to be at the top choose views-view.tpl.php otherwise choose something more specific.

Create a file in your theme folder titled with one of these title options. Click the blue Display output link and copy the code into the file you just created. Save. Clear cache. Congratulations you have now overridden the View theme template.

Find the code

```
  <?php if ($pager): ?>
    <?php print $pager; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

and move it to the top of the code where you want the pager to be. Save.

Comment: This really helped me out but i'm still confused. In my situation I am looking to alter the output of the tags associated with each node. Currently they display like so: tag,tag,tag I would like them to display like such: tag \ tag \ tag can this process help me achieve this?